# How to convert a RFC3339-String into a NSDate

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am trying to convert a RFC3339 formatted String Object to the corresponding NSDateObject :
A received String looks like this : `2012-10-29T00:00:00+01:00`
I tried to use a NSDateFormatter but i dont know the correct specifiers ?
Any Ideas how to do this the right way ?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss???????"]; // ?????
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:startAtString];
```

Comment: Traditionally you have to remove the last `:` in a preprocessing step, but I've heard rumors of a recent formatter code addition that can handle things without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside one of my project I have this routine:

```
-(NSDate *)convertUTCStringToDate:(NSString *)utcDateString {
     NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
     return [df dateFromString:utcDateString];
}
```